# small problem In Pascal , Could you please help?

Tags: pascal

I write this program with pascal 
which ask the user to enter two arrays and constant value which is K 
the program muli the K with arrays .
and then save the answer in new array
and do some operation in new array
addition << work well
Subtraction << also work
BUT the problem in Multi << I am trying to ask the user to enter a new array and do Muti but still there is a problem.
ALSO
I want these operation repeated until the user press exit <<< I could not do this options because i am not perfect with pascal .

I would be grateful if you could help me

This is My Code

```
program BST6;

const maxN=100;maxM=100;
type mat=array[1..maxN,1..maxM]of integer;
var A,B,c:mat;
    n,m,l,s,i,j,k:integer;
    ch : char;

procedure readMat(var A:mat;var m,n:integer);
begin
for i:=1 to m do
    for j:=1 to n do
        begin
        write('mat[',i,',',j,']=');
        readln(A[i,j]);
        end;
end;

procedure writeMat(A:mat;m,n:integer);
begin
for i:=1 to m do
    begin
    for j:=1 to n do
        write(a[i,j]:4);
    writeln;
    end;
end;

function multK(A:mat;k:integer):mat;
begin
for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to m do
        begin
        B[i,j]:= K*A[i,j];
        end;
multK:=B;
end;

function minus(A,B:mat):mat;
begin
for i:=1 to m do
    for j:=1 to n do
        C[i,j]:=A[i,j]-B[i,j];
minus:=C;
end;

function plus(A,B:mat):mat;
begin
for i:=1 to m do
    for j:=1 to n do
        C[i,j]:=A[i,j]+B[i,j];
plus:=C;
end;

function mult(A,B:mat;m,l,n:integer):mat;
begin
for i:=1 to m do
    for j:=1 to n do
        for k:=1 to l do
            c[i,j]:=c[i,j]+A[i,k]*B[k,j];
mult:=C;
end;

begin
write('input m<=',maxM,'.. m=' );readln(m);
write('input n<=',maxN,'.. n=');readln(n);
readMat(A,m,n);
writeln('input the const K');readln(k);
B:=multK(A,K);
writeln('The matrix A : ');
writeMat(A,m,n);
writeln('The matrix B=K*A : ');
writeMat(B,m,n);
writeln('choose the operation + , - or * ');
readln(ch);


case ch of
'+' : c:=plus(A,B);
'-' : c:=minus(A,B);
'*' : begin
      writeln('input m<=',maxM,'input l<=',maxN);readln(m,l);readMat(A,m,l);
      writeln('input l<=',maxN);readln(n);readMat(B,l,n);
      c:=mult(A,B,m,l,n);
      end;

end;
writeMat(c,m,n);
readln;
end.
```

Comment: First, what is your problem?  State it clearly.  Is it a compilation error, or some sort of runtime error, and what is it specifically in either case?  Second, can you cut this down to something shorter that still fails in the same way?  This not only makes it easier for anybody trying to help you, but may help you see the problem.

Comment: the problem in muli op. if u could help me i am waiting for u.

Comment: You should at least describe the difference between the observed and expected behavior. But your real problem isn't that bug, but that you write unreadable code.

Comment: you can run the program . and see it .

Comment: i know that the problem is not big . so i am asking for help . just a part not whole program

Comment: @user570285:  I don't have a Pascal compiler where I am.  I likely have one on my home systems, but haven't checked.  This doesn't mean I can't read Pascal programs and help with them, but it does mean I'm looking at a really badly written program for an undefined error.  Since you seemingly refuse to trim the program down, rewrite it to be understandable, or tell us the error, I question how badly you need the help.  You don't seem interested in helping us help you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all having global one letter variables which collide with function parameters with the same name is insane.

Why does `multK` modify the global variable `B` as a sideeffect?
Why does `minus` modify the global variable `C` as a sideeffect?
Why global integers as for index variables?
And `mult` is even worse: It doesn't only modify `C` as a sideeffect, but it assumes C contains meaningful values beforehand. I think it needs to initialize `C` to all zeros beforehand.

My guess is some of your side effects interfere in strange ways. But I don't want to think it through. Refactor your code first. In particular learn how and when to use local variables.

Comment: in multi op. i want the program to multi array a with array b and save result in c , and also want these op. to be repeated. if u have any other suggestions or any help I need it now

Comment: The Question is how to multiply two matrix using pascal ?

Comment: @user570285:  The question of how to multiply matrices using Pascal is much too broad to be a good SO question.  If you were to rewrite your code as suggested by this answer, retry it, and tell us what specifically is going wrong, we could be much more useful.

Comment: when the user choose * he has to enter new matrices .

Comment: i want the program to multi the old matrices A and B ?

Comment: if u could help me i will be grateful .